# Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported. https://crbug.com/558377

Tags: android, firebase, android-webview

I am getting the crashes in firebase for my app and receiving the error as **Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported. https://crbug.com/558377**.

How can I fix this error.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Using WebView from more than one process at once with the same data directory is not supported. https://crbug.com/558377 : Current process (pid 23927), lock owner unknown
org.chromium.android_webview.AwDataDirLock.b
    
org.chromium.android_webview.AwDataDirLock.b (chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-447216434:27)
    ev0.i (chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-447216434:34)
    dv0.run (chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-447216434:2)
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8512)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```